# Variable might not have been initialized, don't understand why

Tags: java

So I'm in an intro Java course, making a grade calculator with the added task of adjusting grades on this set of conditions:

If the student has done the bonus work:

- The Exam 1 grade is either:

  - 80% of Exam 2’s grade if it is higher than the original Exam 1 grade, or
  - the original Exam 1 grade.
- The Exam 2 grade is either:

  - 80% of Exam 3’s grade if it is higher than the original Exam 2 grade, or
  - the original Exam 2 grade.

The modification is always made for Exam 1 first.

I've tried this first with the exam 1 grade, attempting to assign `g1n` the value `g2 * 0.8` if `(g2 * 0.8) > g1`, and giving it the value of `g1` otherwise. I'm having trouble seeing how `g1n` isn't being initialized since it seems to me like the conditions I've just listed are exhaustive.

Below is the relevant part of my code. What gives?

```
// declare variables
int g1;
int g2;
int g3;
char grade;
double g1n;
double g2n;
double avg;
String bonus;

// get input
System.out.println("***************  Grade Computer *************");
System.out.println("Enter the student's first name: ");
String first = input.next();
System.out.println("Enter the student's middle initial: ");
String mid = input.next();
System.out.println("Enter the student's last name: ");
String last = input.next();
System.out.println("Enter EXAM 1 grade: ");
g1 = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter EXAM 2 grade: ");
g2 = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter EXAM 3 grade: ");
g3 = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Was bonus work done? [yes/no]: ");
bonus = input.next();
System.out.println(g1 + " " + g2 + " " + g3 + " " + bonus);

// adjust exam scores if necesssary
if (bonus.equals("yes")) {
    if (((double)g2 * 0.8) > g1) {
        g1n = ((double)g2 * 0.8);
    } else {
        g1n = (double)g1;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I changed it to this and am still getting the same message...

```
if (bonus.equals("yes")) {
    if (((double)g2 * 0.8) > g1) {
        g1n = ((double)g2 * 0.8);
    }
    if (((double)g3 * 0.8) > g2) {
        g2n = ((double)g3 * 0.8);
    }
} else {
    g1n = (double)g1;
    g2n = (double)g2;
}

// compute average
avg = (g1n + (double)g2 + (double)g3) / 3;
```

Comment: You have just moved the problem from one branch to the other.  If your first `if`, you have two `if`s, but not `else`s.  Which means that it is possible to enter the first `if` (`bonus` equals `"yes"`), but not enter any of the inner `if`s (small `g2` and small `g3`).  This error occurs because you aren't accounting for all scenarios.  You should initialize the variable or cover all possible branches.

Answer (score 3):

If `bonus` does not equal `"yes"`, then `g1n` is never set.

Comment: Just add an else for the outer if with `g1n = g1`.

Answer (score 1):

The only place that `g1n` is set is in the `if (bonus.equals("yes"))` clause. If `bonus` is not equal to `"yes"`, then `g1n` is never set. Your existing `else` provides an `else` to the second `if`. You can't add a nonexistent variable to another.

You can trace through your program if `g1n` is not equal to `"yes"`. Nowhere does it assign a value to `g1n`, unless `bonus.equals("yes")`.

Fix this by saying after the `if` clause, `else { g1n = 0; }`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because g1n could be not initialized.

```
if (bonus.equals("yes")) {  // if bonus is yes

    if (((double)g2 * 0.8) > g1) {

        g1n = ((double)g2 * 0.8);
    } 
        else {

            g1n = (double)g1; 
    }

    // compute average
    avg = (g1n + (double)g2 + (double)g3)/3;
}
```

g1n can be still null if bonus is something else than "yes". So just get the avg calculation into your if as above.